# restrict the number of rows returned from search

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I search in windows (that contain dw retrieve its data from sqlserver database)either by using argument or filter

if there are 5000 rows(for example) that satisfy search criteria

1. I don't want to retrieve all rows that satisfy search criteria ,  I want to retrieve only first 50 rows and display it in window - (as  database is on web) and displaying (in bottom of window ) numbers to indicate there are other output  pages for search.
2. When user click (for example no 3 dw begins to  retrieve the third page according to search criteria and if user  click no 9 dw begins to  retrieve the 9th page according to search criteria)

how can i do this (with out using rows as needed as i had sort and in multi user it may lock table) ?

as for example any page on web that you search for specific product in  amazon as shown below as seen in the last line of amazon

[image: Amazon Example]

Previous Page 1 2 3 ... 154 Next Page

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you.

In the datawindow of 5000 rows includes the following SELECT with the arguments: max_row and min_row. Just do Retrieve with the values of the argument you want.

Pagination with Oracle statements:

```
select * from (
 select a.*, rownum rnum
 from ( INCLUDE_THE_SELECT_ORIGINAL_HERE ) a
 where rownum <= MAX_ROWS )
 where rnum >= MIN_ROWS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just include

LIMIT 0 , 50

On the end of your original SQL code